# MAMP Pro mysql can't start

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

I'm having problem can't find way to fix this. I get this error

```
2017-01-11 23:58:25 7fffbac563c0  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
170111 23:58:26 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Any suggestion how can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can edit MySQL `my.cnf` solve this problem.

find: `file -> edit template -> MYsql(my.cnf)`

find: `'innodb_force_recovery' = 1`

Hope to help you!

Comment: Thank you. May be you also can answer why it happens?

Comment: Here’s a litte more info on what this does: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html